# What is the proper way to dispose of a medicinal substance?

Tags: biochemistry, lab-techniques, medicinal-chemistry

Is there a protocol or a set of guidelines to safely dispose off a batch of expired drugs (as a manufacturer)? I guess the process may vary for different drugs. My specific question regarding the safe disposal of expired [amlodipine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amlodipine); which is better — incineration or landfill or any other technique?

Comment: Usually you would return to the pharmacy of purchase for safe denaturing

Comment: @RoryM OP is asking from a manufacturer's point of view.

Comment: Chemically inactivating the drug (in a safe manner) is probably best - bleach, peroxide, other reactants that can themselves then be neutralized.